# Comodo certificate setting up with Heroku failing

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install comodo positive certificate on heroku app.
I baught a certificate from comodo. and followed heroku's guide of Manually Acquiring an SSL/TLS Certificate. I believe everything went smooth here. I can see this message in SSL section on heroku's app page as well.

```
Your certificate www.app-name.com expires on March 26, 2020
```

then it asked me to update DNS targets. SO I removed the old once now they look as follows:

```
     Domain Name                             DNS Target

    app-name.com      ------        app-name.com.herokudns.com

    www.app-name.com  ------        www.app-name.com.herokudns.com
```

this dns target value is auto set by heroku, all i can SET is DOMAIN NAME. DNS target is auto populated

PS: now when i visit www.app-name.com.herokudns.com, I cannot see my app.
I can only see my app on this link.

```
app-name.herokuapp.com
```

When I do

> heroku certs

I get following output

```
Name            |      Common Name(s)       |  Expires  | Trusted   |Type
dilopurus-77213 | www.app-name.com,app-name.com | future-date | True | SNI
```

I used Godaddy for buying Domain name. so I went to godaddy added my

```
CNAME-----WWW------app-name.herokudns.com
```

Now I cant even access my app on registered domain as I am getting an error site cannot be reached. I do not know what is wrong in the flow. I exactly followed what was asked for.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?